# How does one do intrusion prevention/monitoring in the Azure Web App environment?

Tags: azure

I am trying to secure my MVC4 web app on Azure. I am sure Azure has built in Intrusion preventing and monitoring, but I cannot find anything. I am sure they must have a tool/service.

Ideally I need to see evidence of strange behaviour. Ironically I get much of this from Elmah which shows weird exceptions from repeat accesses from one IP address, basically hits on my login page, but no further.

I am considering a third party WAF to Azure such as Cloudflare, but I would have thought they would offer their own service.

I am using "Standard" App Services and SQL Azure instances.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [Azure Security Center](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/security-center/)? This offers a number of functions around threat detection, including the ability to hook your application up to Web Application Firewalls such as Barracuda.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will check out Azure Security Center. I am aware of Barracuda and was also looking at Cloudflare's WAF. It will be interesting to see if I can just use the "Security Center" instead of having to invest in extra WAFs outside of Azure.

Comment: @SamJolly You are able to configure both Barracuda and FS WAF solutions through security center, when you do this it also means that all the logging from the WAF is available through security center, which can be quite convenient.

Comment: Is it possible to monitor Web Apps within security centre? I can only see VMs, Network and SQL. Probably missing something very simple.. Looks good though.

Comment: You enable it at the subscription level and it should then pick up all the resources and start giving reccomendations on them. However I am not sure how much monitoring of web apps it does without you enabling the WAF component, which obviously costs extra. I suspect it is the WAF that does most of the web app monitoring, which then reports into security centre. Its all integrated though, you enable the WAF through security centre.